# What is a good maximum files size of an SWF file on the web?

Tags: flash, filesize

This kind of question must have been answered many times over and over again. But since I can't find it answered her on stackoverflow, I'm asking it one more time:

Is there a reasonable upper limit for the file size of a SWF file sent to a client over the web?

EDIT: This will be an magazine-like SWF, derived from PDF. The user expects a lot of text and images.

Comment: The answer here is rather subjective and IMHO it primarily depends on what "sent" to the client means. Are you shoving an advertisement or Flash-based landing page down user's throats, or are they expecting a game or Flash application?

Comment: @lc: i edited the question to meet your comment - anyway, do you see issues arising from the number of megabytes hold within the memory of a user's Flash VM?

Comment: I don't think there's a hard maximum and I've seen some games out there that take up more than a GB of memory. I think the real issue is download time more than anything else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this comment answered the question:

> I don't think there's a hard maximum and I've seen some games out there that take up more than a GB of memory. I think the real issue is download time more than anything else. – lc.